# Definition of "Current Task Estimate"

Tags: agile, metrics, kanban

In the book "Agile Project Management with Kanban," the author Eric Brechner defines "current task estimate" as the sum of pending, active, and done tasks.

I do not understand why "done" tasks are included in this metric. Ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Where did you get this definition from? I'm reading this definition from the chapter "Estimate your work", which doesn't include done work.

[image]